# How to loop through, while adding onto string?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I need to loop through an array and populate a string in the following way

First --> string = array(0) + array(1) + array (2)

Then --> string = array(1) + array (2)

Then --> string = array(2)

How can I accomplish this if the length of the array is dynamic?
I am using vb.net
Thank you!

Comment: Have you got anything so far? You can get the length of an array using `.Length`

Comment: if I use for i=0 to array.count 
string = string + array(i)
will work for the first time around but the second time I want without array(0)

Comment: So you need a way to increase i and run the loop again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 `for` loops to accomplish this.  The first `for` loop would loop through the whole array and the send loop would be looping through the portion of the array that you want to add to the string.

```
var tempList = new ArrayList();
tempList.Add("Test1");
tempList.Add("Test2");
tempList.Add("Test3");

var tempString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < tempList.Count; j++)
    {
        tempString.Append(tempList[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see any benefit from taking the OPs arrays and creating an array list?

Comment: switched it over to vb
for i=0 to templist.count
for j=i to templist.count
tempstring.append(templist(j))
next
Next